# Why did K&R not define data type lengths better?

Tags: c, types, language-history

Every modern programming language I've encountered has well-defined data types. Java, for example, has an `int` that is exactly 32 bits and a `long` that is exactly 64 bits. This is not implementation specific but built into the spec itself. C, on the other hand, has a `short` that is at least 16 bits, an `int` that is at least 16 bits, and a `long` that is at least 32 bits. Because it is defined as *at least*, though, they can be much larger, which results in serious portability issues.

I have never understood this. I have always chalked it up to being the result of differing hardware standards in the 1970's, but this doesn't actually make sense to me. Even if there were a lot of computers that couldn't handle 64 bit data types, that still doesn't excuse not defining a `short` as *necessarily* 16 bits  and an `int` as *necessarily* 32 bits. From the standards we already see 32 bits as a minimum requirement for any hardware.

This proliferation of standards has resulted in advice like the following, taken from the article [How to C (as of 2016)](https://matt.sh/howto-c):

> If you find yourself typing `char` or `int` or `short` or `long` or `unsigned`
>   into new code, you’re doing it wrong.
>
> For modern programs, you should `#include <stdint.h>`then use standard
>   types.
>
> For more details, see the `stdint.h` specification.
>
> The common standard types are:
>
> - `int8_t`, `int16_t`, `int32_t`, `int64_t` — signed integers
> - `uint8_t`, `uint16_t`, `uint32_t`, `uint64_t` — unsigned integers
> - `float` — standard 32-bit floating point
> - `double` - standard 64-bit floating point
>
> Notice we don’t have `char` anymore. char is actually misnamed and misused in C.
>
> Developers routinely abuse `char` to mean “`byte`” even when they are
>   doing unsigned `byte` manipulations. It’s much cleaner to use `uint8_t` to
>   mean single a unsigned-byte/octet-value and `uint8_t *` to mean
>   sequence-of-unsigned-byte/octet-values.

I've also noticed quite a bit of advice recommending the use of `size_t` as the standard go to `int` replacement, as in [Modern C by Jens Gustedt](http://icube-icps.unistra.fr/img_auth.php/d/db/ModernC.pdf) which uses a `size_t` as the control variable in a `for` loop in the very first example of the book.

## My question is two fold:

### 1. Why did K&R 2 not define data types more definitely in 1978?

### 2. What, in 2018, are we *supposed* to do with our data type choices, or is it all just style and convention and highly opinionated?

Comment: One of the original C computers had 36 bit ints with 9 bit chars. Where would **you** use C now if it was defined as such back then?

Comment: Look at Mr. Fancy Computer Owner with 32-bit `int` in the 1970s. La de da. No, 32-bit was not a hardware requirement for implementing C back then.

Comment: In other words the answer _is_ hardware limitations of 1978. I couldn't find the dupe original. Thank you for the pointer.

Comment: I didn't downvote so here's a counter. Jens is a regular answerer to C questions on Stack Overflow. Matt's writing contains some questionable choices on the other hand. You should use `size_t` as the loop variable for loops that index arrays (most do!)

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Thanks; I've always wondered why SO culture penalizes duplicates that are uniquely worded. An increase in SEO optimization would help people find their answers better. Question: that dupe original just answers the first part of my question, and you only give limited advice; do you know of a resource that answers #2 more thoroughly?

Comment: @malan there are *bad* duplicates. Like most of the C duplicates now are bad. They're not real duplicates in that there is no [mcve]; there are 1000 lines of code with error on one; that error being answered in another.

Comment: @malan as for "what should we do", that is off-topic for Stack Overflow as primarily opinionated, but I remember some...

Comment: Using `size_t` for a loop variable is correct if the loop is over container indices, since `size_t` is an unsigned type wide enough to contain the size of any object. IOW, it must be OK for an index. That does not make it a "goto int replacement". `int`s are used for many things other than container indices.

Comment: but again, *plurality, if not majority, of `for` loops* with a counter is iterating indices...

Comment: The early '70s really were the Wild West where computer hardware was concerned.  Not only did different architectures have different word sizes, they may also have had padding bits within integral types, and they may have used something other than 2's complement for signed integer representation.  That's why the C standard guarantees that a type can represent a minimum *range of values*, rather than contain a minimum number of bits or bytes.  As long as you respect those value limits and don't make any assumptions about how values are represented, your code will be *highly* portable.

Comment: As for what to use - if you care about *values* rather than representation, and you want your code to be portable to anything with a C compiler, use the traditional types (`int`, `short`, `long`, etc.).  If you care about *representation* (i.e., for bit twiddling) and you're not so concerned about portability (i.e., you only care about modern desktop and server systems), then use the `stdint` types (`int16_t`, `uint8_t`, etc.).